# Socket.io stopped working after porting from 'express' to 'express.io'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Here is the code:

```
var app = require('express.io')();
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var options = {
privateKey : fs.readFileSync(path1).toString(),
certificate : fs.readFileSync(path2).toString()
};

app.https(options).io();


//doesn't work anymore
app.post('/posts', function(req, res){ (...) }

//still works
app.listen(port, function()) 

//doens't work anymore
app.on('connection', function(socket){ (...) }
```

This happened after I ported socket.io from http to https (ssl). Can someone help me out on this one please?

Comment: From what I'm finding, the problem may exist on the client side. Are you connecting to https or wss in your client code?

Comment: @azurelogic thank you for replying azure. I'm connecting with var `io(https_url + ':3000', { secure: true, 'connect timeout': 5000 });`. There is indeed a javascript error with `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` but app.post('/posts') isn't work neither way... It's all strange

Comment: Is there a reason you're using app.post() with no app.get()? As for the options object, it looks like `{secure: true}` is not needed with newer versions of socket.io. Based on the source, the url is used to determine that.